# How to make cell color change based on value

Tags: excel, colors, cell, vba

```
  Dim c As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


 If Left(c, 1) = "X" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
 If Left(c, 1) = "L" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
 If Left(c, 1) = "C" Then c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)


Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

How can I get the cell change the interior color (let's say to light blue) after condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `c.Interior.colorIndex = 8`

The list of color codes can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx).

**EDIT:**

Following your comments the full code would be:

```
 Dim c As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

     If Left(c, 1) = "X" Or Left(c, 1) = "L" Or Left(c, 1) = "C" Then
        c = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 1)
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
     End If

Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I think my question was not too clear...    c.Interior.colorIndex = 8   will change the colors of all cells in G column, I'd like to have only cells which met removal of  X, C, L conditions changed color to blue

Comment: @DariuszJezewski see Edit

Answer (score 0):

There's built-in support for conditional formatting already: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67

No need to reinvent the wheel.